# Error while creating woocommerce product category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Running wordpress locally and try to create category for woocommerce product

```
 $term = wp_insert_term( $_term, 'product_cat', array( 'parent' => intval( $parent ) ) );
```

Error is this

> object(WP_Error)#629 (3) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "Invalid taxonomy." } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } ["additional_data":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Answer (score 0):

It depends on when you try to input the term as the WooCommerce taxonomy `product_cat` is not there at different stages of the WP initialization process.

Example at WordPress `init` hook:

```php
add_action('init', function() {
  var_dump(taxonomy_exists( 'product_cat' ));
});
```

```
bool(false)
```

whereas running the same for example in the `woocommerce_before_main_content` hook of WooCommerce:

```
bool(true)
```

The earliest point in time when your statement will work is with the action/hook called `woocommerce_after_register_taxonomy` (see [WooCommerce GitHub Repository](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-post-types.php#L280)) because all core WooCommerce taxonomies are created by then.

At which point in time are you trying to add the term to the taxonomy?

Comment: i want to run it without action/hook 

can i do that ?

Comment: In general: No as explained above. If you just add it somewhere in the code, the taxonomy won't be there already. At which point in time do you need it, i.e. under which circumstances should it be added?

Comment: i have a plugin where i calling an external api and importing the categories

Comment: can we quick chat about it ?

Comment: Of course! Where?

Comment: can you join here https://stin.to/mdehy

Comment: are you still in the chat ?